# How to call WordPress won jQuery in functions.php proper way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am converting an HTML theme into WordPress. I am calling Wordpress jQuery using this function -

```
function insert_jquery(){
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts','insert_jquery');
```

It's call WordpRess jQuery but not working all jquery elements properly. My main slider  is not working, but others slider is working. How can can can I fix?

And I am using this to call other jQuery-

```
function load_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to replace change $ in your jQuery to 'jQuery'. E.g.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    // code here 
});
```

But your question doesn't give enough information to go on. What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: A bit more information on why you have to do this: WordPress runs jQuery in noConflict() mode, that's why the dollar sign won't wory: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ | http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers